# Break out of a Java call or Callbacks or something similar in R

Tags: java, r, activemq-classic, rjava

I use this package called "Rjms" which is a wrapper for RJava for pushing/consuming from an apache activeMQ. There is a function called "consume" in the package which I use to consume from a queue. The problem is that once I make that call, till a message is received from the queue, the application is suspended. If it so happens that the queue is empty, the whole script is just suspended. I want to add a time out of some kind so that if the message does not come for say 5 mins then I want to dismiss the call.

Once the call is made in R, it is internally calling some Java functions( I am assuming). Hence I am not sure if R can interrupt this process at all. I was reading up on callbacks and seemed like a good idea but could not find anything concrete to use in R. I am not sure if I can give a reproducible example as a Apache ActiveMQ needs to be setup first. But in general is there a way to come out of a function call which is not native to R?

Any help will be appreciated.

Link - Rjms Package - http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rjms/Rjms.pdf

Comment: Note that since this question was asked, the ‘Rjms’ package has been removed from the CRAN repository.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to what R is doing exactly but it sounds as if its calling the blocking MessageConsumer#receive method which will just wait forever for a message to arrive.  There is a timed alternative but I don't know if you have access to that.  Normally you can break this method by closing the MessageConsumer via a call to its close() method, if you can make a call that invokes that then it should break and return null, or possibly throw an exception I forget which.  I don't know much about R so can't offer any other suggestion, breaking a blocking call tends to vary from case to case.